# Find index of fulfilled promise inside Promise.race

Tags: javascript, promise, puppeteer

I have the following code. I need to find which waitForFunction resulted in the race being fulfilled. How can I do so, preferably storing the index of the fulfilled promise?

```
await Promise.race([
                page.waitForFunction(() => {
                    let element = document.body.innerHTML.search("found1");
                    //@ts-ignore
                    if (element !== -1) {
                        console.log('elem 1')
                        return true
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }
                }),

                page.waitForFunction(() => {
                    let element2 = document.body.innerHTML.search("found2");
                    //@ts-ignore
                    if (element2 !== -1) {
                        console.log('elem 2')
                        return true
                    } else {
                        return false
                    }
                }),
            ])
```

Comment: Use `return ["found1", true]` etc

Comment: If I do ans = await Promise.race, it returns a JSHandle object which doesn't really tell much about the index

Comment: `Promise.race` returns a `Promise` that fulfills or rejects from the iterable passed based on which one executed and resolved fastest. In your case your callback for `waitForNavigation` should return some value to identify itself or its function rather than plain Boolean values. You can see what @Bergi suggested that gives you a way to identify the fulfilled promise. If you don't like nested array, you can also use objects.

Comment: @Aizaz It returns the promise that fulfills fastest, not an array of fulfilled and pending promises. If you still want to check specifically for fulfillment, you can check this non standard method of patching native Promise: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/317/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-promise-has-been-fulfilled-rejected-or-resolved

Comment: @AbrarHossain Don't patch native objects. Just use `Promise.any` instead of `Promise.race` if you are only interested in the first fulfillment.